# How to prevent users from deleting all data under certain path in Firebase database with security rules?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a VERY simple data structure:

```
{
  "article-favorites" : {
    "-KKEIhw6SZ9W0tjyj_qO" : {
      "xn19qiJXmJMDEMzqwB8IQHbHzAG3" : true
    },
    "-KKOd-3pUTrM01L5XIXC" : {
      "YJnErzTYGoWw6xCO2mQfmP0ftVt1" : true,
      "xn19qiJXmJMDEMzqwB8IQHbHzAG3" : true
    },
    "-KKPxI9Z40e0Lq8Oa00L" : {
      "xn19qiJXmJMDEMzqwB8IQHbHzAG3" : true
    }
  }
}
```

Where the first key is article id, the second is user id.
These are my rules:

```
"article-favorites": {
  "$article_id": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    "$uid": {
      ".write": "$uid == auth.uid"
    }
  }
}
```

The problem with these rules is that user will never be allowed to favorite an article because he will not be allowed to create a new article_id entry. But then again if I add write rule to article_id path I can't figure out how to not allow user just to overwrite all article_id path with whatever data or to delete other user favorites. I have run out of ideas...

This needs to be a common problem and needs to have a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okey guys, after couple of days of frustration, this is how I managed to solve this:

```
"article-favorites": {
    "$article_id": {
    ".read": "auth != null ",
    ".write": "auth != null && !data.exists() && newData.val().length == 1 && newData.child(auth.uid).exists()",
    "$uid": {
      ".write": "$uid == auth.uid"
    }
  }
}
```

To explain, uid check stays the same, but in order to allow to write new article_id entry, there can't be any previous data for that id, and the new data must contain only key with currently authorized user.

Comment: The problem for me was, that I previously thought there was no point of two ".write" rules in same tree, since first one overwrites all the deeper ones, but it only overwrites in case it returns "true".